# How can I get the data of a file sended by an API Restful?

Tags: javascript, postman

I need to send a file as part of the body of a request, then from server I have to save it and get the name and size of the file, but when I check the body it has the file content as plain text.

Lang: JS

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If it did, please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available and you should really also let us know what server frameworks you are using. As you said about JS, please see this comprehensive tutorial:

https://blog.logrocket.com/multer-nodejs-express-upload-file/